# How to make two columns into one line (wordpress)?

Tags: css, wordpress, flexbox

I need to make class 3 and 4 in one line.
I tried the following code but it doesn't change the button, two buttons are still in two lines.
Would you please let me know how to solve it?
[image]
Existing code:

```
<form class="acf-fields">
   <div class="1"></div>
   <div class="2">
      <div class="2-1"></div>
      <div class="2-2"></div>
      <div class="2-3"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="3">
      <div class="3-1">
          <input type="submit" class="acfef-submit-button"  value="Sbumit">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="4">
      <input formnovalidate="" type="submit" class="save-progress-button" value="Save Draft" name="save_progress">
   </div>
</form>
```

Code I tried:

```
.acf-fields div:nth-last-of-type(-n+2) {
    display: flex!important;
    flex-direction: row-reverse!important;
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

add `display: inline-block;`

```css
.acf-fields div:nth-last-of-type(-n+2) {
    display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<form class="acf-fields">
   <div class="1"></div>
   <div class="2">
      <div class="2-1"></div>
      <div class="2-2"></div>
      <div class="2-3"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="3">
      <div class="3-1">
          <input type="submit" class="acfef-submit-button"  value="Sbumit">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="4">
      <input formnovalidate="" type="submit" class="save-progress-button" value="Save Draft" name="save_progress">
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi: Thank you for your hlep. I tried it, it works but it display: inline-block all other divs in class 2 as well. I only need to  display: inline-block for class 3 and 4. Would you please let me know how to solve this problem? Thank you.